# How to use Mat-Tree module in Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, treeview, angular-material2

I am trying to implement Tree View [Like](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples)

Angular Version: 4

I copied the related code from above link and paste in my app components but it's showing an error:

So I am looking for the solution like,
How I upgrade from 4 to 5 (Is it necessary only for this module)
Or how to solve those compile time errors

> Typescript error Cannot find module '@angular/core'
>
> Typescript error Cannot find module 'rxjs'

Package.Json:

```
{
  "name": "kalpavriksha-angular-v4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/filesaver": "0.0.30",
    "angular-chat": "^1.0.9",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.2.0",
    "angular-file-picker": "^1.2.0",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.5",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
    "angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.1.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chart.piecelabel.js": "^0.11.0",
    "cloudboost": "^2.0.264",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.11.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.2",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.4.2",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.2.3",
    "datatables.net-select-dt": "^1.2.3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "4.6.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "md-date-picker": "^0.1.0",
    "ng-chat": "^1.0.12",
    "ng-snotify": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.3.1",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.0.27",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.7",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-progress-bar": "0.0.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: try running npm install once again

Comment: Yes I tried npm install but still, errors are there

Comment: I event tried to install each module like @angular/core etc by manually but not work

Answer (score 1):

There are some couple of changes in your package.json file change your

```
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
```

to

```
"rxjs": "5.5.6"
```

also, update your angular/core by

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/core@latest
```

here are the more [details](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10621) if you want regarding update issue.

Comment: Getting error: `The specified command update is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.

Comment: Now only one error is there : `Argument of type '(node: TodoItemNode) => TodoItemNode[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(node: TodoItemNode) => Observable<TodoItemNode[]>'.
  Type 'TodoItemNode[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<TodoItemNode[]>'.
    Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'TodoItemNode[]'.`

Comment: :) this is your development error not angular error you need to debug this!

Comment: Is it because of Typescript version? Or RxJS

Comment: I think because of RXJS check your RXJS import in that file